# Is it possible to create a trigger on a delay using IFTTT?

Tags: if-this-then-that, automation

I have these files on my clould's storage, and I want to create a rule that will share them with say N people (mailing them, or using one of the social networks).

Yet I want to delay this sharing process for X days, each time I enter a code.

Would it be possible using IFTTT? Or should I program it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the way you are looking to do it. While there's a [Date & Time](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time) channel, with triggers of "every hour", "every day at", "every week on the day", "every month on", "every year on", you'd have to set up your action to be an email or social media post with everything already set up.

IFTTT is, literally:

```
If this thing happens, then take this action
```

You can't do

```
If this thing happens, then take this other action in X days
```

You'll have to look for another tool to do this. [Zapier](https://zapier.com) might be the right tool, but I don't use it.